# Airflow:How to select bigquery table data in to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, airflow

I am new in airflow. I created my first dag below, selecting data from google big query table & saving it to a pd dataframe.
Need suggestion in below

1. Where should i provide connection id of my big query
2. As pd.read_gbq requires authintication, how to handle same in airflow dags

import os

```
import pandas as pd

from airflow.contrib.operators import bigquery_operatorfrom  #this will 
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook



def test_gbq():
    sql = "SELECT * FROM `bi-projects-300910.raw_data.production_time_records_cdc`"
    df = pd.read_gbq(sql, dialect='standard')
    print(len(df))


default_args = {'owner': 'Martin james',
                'depends_on_past': False,
                'start_date': datetime(2018, 2, 26, 11, 30),
                'email_on_retry': true,
                'retries': 2
                }

dag = DAG('test_gbq',
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval="0 12 * * *")



testing = PythonOperator(
    task_id="test",
    python_callable=test_python,
    dag=dag)

testing
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, first you should create Service Account (and a key for it) that has access to your BigQuery project and datasets https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts.

Then you will need to set credentials of this service account in pandas https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/authentication.html#authenticating-with-a-service-account

Why won't you use BigQuery Operator in Airflow? https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/authentication.html#authenticating-with-a-service-account IMHO it's a bit easier to setup. After you create a service account you can than setup your connection in Airflow UI and just reference connection id in the operator

Answer (score 0):

Currently MWAA is not compatible with some google tools, but I found this post they explain how to integrate the dependencies from an s3, I am integrating it and it works perfect

[bigquery-and-amazon-managed-apache-airflow](https://hackernoon.com/creating-a-machine-learning-workflow-using-google-bigquery-and-amazon-managed-apache-airflow-c74r31fd)

About the connections, you can add them in the UI.

[/manage-connections](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.2/howto/manage-connections.html)